# SQL LIKE Command trouble searching for '

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, escaping

Hi I am facing a problem with the like command in SQL,

I want to search for special characters within a column .
The special characters are a single quotation mark `'` and `{` and `}`..

I have tried placing these special characters under `[]` but still it doesn't work for `'`

I have also used the except option but that was also of no help..

Waiting for a response soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server escaping is a pain because there are various ways to escape characters, each with different meaning and use case.

A single quote is escaped with another single quote: `WHERE myfield LIKE '%''%'`.

Comment: @Egalitarian, as far as single quotes goes, it's the same for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a value which has single quote, [you need to double it.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2008/02/19/understanding-single-quotes.aspx)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Northwind
WHERE   Summary LIKE 'single''quotes%'
```

Comment: Does this work for the oracle database also ???
just in case if u have any idea???

Comment: @Egalitarian, as far as single quotes goes, it's the same for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this-

```
select * from <table> where <column> like '%''%'
```

Comment: @Egalitarian, as far as single quotes goes, it's the same for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to escape the special character like so:

```
SELECT .... WHERE my_column like '%\'%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: even i was shocked when that didn't work when i initially tries...
thanx anyways